PyTorch DataLoader hangs when num_workers > 0 with custom torchvision transform
I’m using PyTorch’s DataLoader to load my dataset. I’ve noticed that my program hangs indefinitely during training when I set num_workers > 0. However, it works fine when num_workers = 0.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
class MedianFilter:
    def __init__(self, kernel_size=3):
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size

    def __call__(self, img):
        return img

train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
    MedianFilter(),
    transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=40, translate=(0.125, 0.125)),
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=(28, 28), scale=(1, 1), ratio=(1, 1), interpolation=InterpolationMode.BILINEAR),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])
val_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
    MedianFilter(),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

train_dataset = ImageFolder(root='../Dataset/Original/train/', transform=train_transform)
val_dataset = ImageFolder(root='../Dataset/Original/val/', transform=val_transform)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, pin_memory=True, num_workers=3, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=64, pin_memory=True, num_workers=3)

dataloader = {'train':train_dataloader, 'val':val_dataloader}

def train_model(model, dataloader, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs):

    acc_history = {'train' : [], 'val' : []}
    loss_history = {'train' : [], 'val' : []}
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(1, num_epochs+1):
        print(f"Epoch{epoch}:")

        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()
            else:
                model.eval()
            running_correct = 0
            running_loss = 0.0
            totalIm = 0
            for data, _label in dataloader[phase]: # Stuck here

In this code, the MedianFilter class is a simple identity function. Despite this, the program still hangs when num_workers > 0.
Why is this happening and how can I resolve this issue?
I have tried to simplify the MedianFilter class to a simple identity function that just returns the input image. Despite this simplification, the program still hangs when num_workers > 0. I expected that this change would resolve the issue, as the MedianFilter class is no longer doing any significant computation. However, the problem persists.
I have also tried running the code without the custom torchvision transform and setting num_workers > 0. In this case, the code runs as expected.

It sounds like there are no workers to respond to the Dataloader's queries. You can verify by breaking the program and seeing where the program was when broken. If you find it in a worker loop, check how you are initializing your workers.
